# Does jQuery re-query the DOM when $(this) is called?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following code, when `$(this)` is called, does jQuery re-query the DOM as though a selector has been passed to it (using some property of the object as a selector), or does jQuery retain the previously returned object?

```
$('.someButton').on('click', function() {
    $(this).remove();  // Is this another lookup, or just a wrapper for the previously returned object?
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't re-query the DOM, `this` is already an element. jQuery simply sets the context to the element, adjusts the length, and returns itself. This code is from the `init` function, which runs when you do `$(something)`, this is part of a big `if..else` statement, where it also checks for selectors, arrays among other things:

```
// HANDLE: $(DOMElement)
} else if (selector.nodeType) {
  this.context = this[0] = selector;
  this.length = 1;
  return this;
```

So basically it just wraps the element in a new jQuery object.

Comment: Thanks for answering with a reference to the source.  This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: And to promote this answer that I agree with, here is performance-based proof to show there is no re-lookup using `$(this)` http://jsperf.com/this-slowing-us-down